# React Native expo referencing old 'ghost state' when refreshed

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo, use-effect, use-state

So I'm developing a react native app using expo and firebase. The component first receives `initialData` from its parent component, who downloaded it from a firebase server, and sets it as a state. Whenever the user changes the state in the front-end, the code uploads it to the server. `useIsMounting()` is a custom hook to check if the component is first mounted.

```js
const MyComponent = ({initialData} => {
  
  const [data, setData] = useState<number[]>([])
  const isMounting = useIsMounting()
  
  const uploadData = () => {
    myUpLoadFunction(data).then(() => {
      console.log('upload success, size of data: ' + data.length)
    })
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setData(initialData)
  }, [])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if(!isMounting) {
      uploadData(data)
    }
  }, [data])

  return(
    <View>
    ...
  )
})
```

The problem is when i make a change to the data in the front-end and **refresh** the app by saving the code. Instead of just calling `uploadData()` once, it calls it twice by uploading the current state first, and *immediately after* that, uploading the old state before the change. Interestingly, this problem does not happen when I **reload** the app by pressing the reload button in expo go.

For example, let's say `initialData` was an array of size 5. I then delete one element. And then I refresh the app. This is what my console looks like.

```
download complete
upload success, size of data: 5  //initial data
upload success, size of data: 4  //after data delete
upload success, size of data: 4  //after refresh
upload success, size of data: 5  //immediately after, uploads the old 'ghost state'
```

When I check the firebase database after this, the data has changed back to 5 elements. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you should look into realtime updates for changes in firebase db/firestore. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen